# jQuery slider in a Python/Django SessionWizardView

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.x, django, jquery-ui

I have created a Data Verification page in a Django `SessionWizardView` where a user has to confirm an earlier submitted rating of an image using a jQuery UI Slider (-100 - +100)

The below slider starts off at the same point the user has previously rated the image at by adding a Django template variable. `value: {{first_slider}},`

My issue is that I would prefer to 'externalise' this script or to somehow otherwise condense it as I will need to add nine of such to the page.

I tried to make an external JS file and include the necessary Django template tags but this did not work.

**wizard_form.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block head %}
{{ wizard.form.media }}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<h1>Experiment</h1>

<p>Page: {{ wizard.steps.step1 }} of {{ wizard.steps.count }}</p>

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <table>   
        {{ wizard.management_form }}
            {% if wizard.form.forms %}
                {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
                {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
                    {{ form }}
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                {{ wizard.form }}
        {% endif %}   
    </table>

    {% load staticfiles %}  
    {% if 'surveyone' in request.path %}                        
             {% if wizard.steps.current in steps %}     
                    <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{display_image}}" height="600" width="500" style="border:1px solid black;" align="middle"/>                                                                     

                    <div class="slider" id="one"></div>                             
                    <div id="slider-result"></div>   
                    <input type="text" name="slider_value" id="hidden1"/>                           
                    <section></section>   
                    <script src="{% static "survey/js/slider_two.js" %}"></script>                  
            {% endif %} 
            {% if wizard.steps.current in dv_steps %}       

            <img src="{% static "survey/images/pathone/" %}{{first_image}}{{fourth_image}}{{seventh_image}}" height="300" width="250" style="border:1px solid black;" align="middle"/>                          
                      <div class="slider_three" id="one"></div>                     
                        <script >                                                                               
                            $('#submit').click(function() {
                                var username = $('#hidden').val();
                                if (username == "") username = 0;  
                                $.post('comment.php', {
                                    hidden: username
                                }, function(return_data) {
                                    alert(return_data);
                                });
                            });

                            $(".slider_three").slider({         
                                animate: true,
                                range: "min",
                                value: {{first_slider}},
                                min: -100,
                                max: +100,
                                step: 1,

                                slide: function(event, ui) { 
                                  $("#slider-result").html(ui.value);
                                  if($(this).attr("id") ==  "one")
                                      $("#hidden1").val(ui.value);
                                }
                            });
                        </script>                                   
                    <div id="slider-result">{{first_slider}}</div>
                    <input type="text" name="slider_value" id="hidden2"/>                           
                    <section></section> 

                    ....
                    ....

    {% if wizard.steps.prev %}
        <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.first }}">{% trans "first step" %}</button>
        <button name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">{% trans "prev step" %}</button>
    {% endif %}

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="{% trans "submit" %}"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to externalise/compact the `$(".someslider").slider()` function, I would do it like this:

1. External script 'sliders_setup.js', depending on jQuery:

   ```
   (function(NAMESPACE){ // to keep things clean
       NAMESPACE.setup_slider = function(selector, value, selector_result){
           $(selector).slider({         
                           animate: true,
                           range: "min",
                           value: value,
                           min: -100,
                           max: +100,
                           step: 1,

                           slide: function(event, ui) { 
                             $(selector_result).html(ui.value);
                             if($(this).attr("id") ==  "one")
                                 $("#hidden1").val(ui.value);
                           }
                       });
       };
   }
   (window.NAMESPACE = window.NAMESPACE || {}));  // again, to keep code clean. Substitute NAMESPACE for any meaningful name you choose.
   ```
2. Include jQuery, include sliders_setup.js, call it (inside  tags) as:

   ```
   NAMESPACE.setup_slider('.slider_three', {{ first_slider }}, '#slider-result');
   ```

Which brings you to one fairly simple line per slider. Since wizard_form.html knows the value of `{{ first_slider }}` it will substitute it and the call to the JavaScript function will pass the integer as intended.